# "An error occurred Application error" Zend Authentication

Tags: php, ubuntu, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I am following tutorial from [here](http://akrabat.com/zend-auth-tutorial/) . And finally when I couldn't do it properly, I just downloaded the code given [there](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/zf-auth-tutorial-200.zip).

My **application.ini** file is

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.db.adapter = "Pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "mypassword"
resources.db.params.dbname = "zf2tutorial"


[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

I use this to run server

```
sudo php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public/ public/index.php
```

And when I go to browser and give URL as `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` and I enter username as "admin" and password as "password", then I get

```
An error occurred
Application error
Exception information:

Message: The supplied parameters to Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable failed to produce a valid sql statement, please check table and column names for validity.
Stack trace:

#0 /usr/share/php/Zend/Auth/Adapter/DbTable.php(369): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->_authenticateQuerySelect(Object(Zend_Db_Select))
#1 /usr/share/php/Zend/Auth.php(117): Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable->authenticate()
#2 /var/www/html/zf-auth-tutorial/application/controllers/AuthController.php(33): Zend_Auth->authenticate(Object(Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable))
#3 /var/www/html/zf-auth-tutorial/application/controllers/AuthController.php(16): AuthController->_process(Array)
#4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): AuthController->indexAction()
#5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#6 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#7 /usr/share/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#8 /usr/share/php/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#9 /var/www/html/zf-auth-tutorial/public/index.php(26): Zend_Application->run()
#10 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'auth',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
  'username' => 'admin',
  'password' => 'ad',
  'login' => 'Login',
)
```

**My SQL is**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  salt varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  role varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  date_created datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

**And to insert a record**

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt, role, date_created) 
VALUES ('admin', SHA1('passwordce8d96d579d389e783f95b3772785783ea1a9854'),
    'ce8d96d579d389e783f95b3772785783ea1a9854', 'administrator', NOW());
```

These queries are as per the tutorials.

Can anyone show me the error?
And I'm not sure if **resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"** is correct in **application.ini** file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and Kervin's answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576637/the-supplied-parameters-to-zend-auth-adapter-dbtable-failed-to-produce-a-valid-s) post, I came to know that

**Removing the 'utf-8' charset in the application.ini solved this for me.**, this line from Kervin's answer did it for me.

Comment: I would recommend you to learn ZF2, because ZF1 is going to die in the first months of 2015 and will not further maintained and supported by ZF community. Happy new year.